# Gravity Forms sending entry data to third-party after submitting in xml

Tags: php, xml, curl, gravityforms

I am fairly new to php/curl and gravity form hooks. I have 5 forms that I'm trying to setup to use the gravity forms gform_after_submission hook so it send xml data to a third party (sbs web service running sql server).

This is what i have already.

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_73', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2);
function post_to_third_party($entry, $form) {

$post_url = 'http://mywebsite.co.uk/customers?clientid=1599999&secret=123';
$body = array(
    'brand' => $entry['20'],
    'product' => $entry['22'],
    'form_id' => $entry['21'],
    'title' => $entry['24'],
    'fname' => $entry['23'],
    'lname' => $entry['17'],
    'postcode' => $entry['14'],
    'address1' => $entry['2.1'],
    'address2' => $entry['2.2'],
    'town' => $entry['2.3'],
    'county' => $entry['2.4']   
    );
$xml = '
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<webform>
        <brand>$brand</brand>
    <product>$product</product>
    <form_id>$form_id</form_id>
    <title>$title</title>
    <fname>$fname</fname>
    <lname>$lname</lname>
    <postcode>$postcode</postcode>
    <address1>$address1</address1>
    <address2>$address2</address2>
    <town>$town</town>
    <county>$county</county>
    </webform>';
var_dump($xml);

$ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $output;
    curl_close($ch);
  }
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Its not sending the xml data to the post url (third party can't see any requests in their server logs). I'm not getting an error either. Just a bit stuck.

Comment: What does `echo $output;` give, if `$output` is false, try `echo curl_error ( $ch );` to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems, which a decent IDE would show you immediately.

1. `function post_to_third_party($entry, $form)`

   `$form` is never used, so just omit it.
2. `$body = array(...);`

   You are never using `$body`, but trying to access the entries 'directly' later.
3. `$xml = '...';`

   Single quoted strings are not interpolated (i.e., variables are not replaced), as `var_dump($xml);` already has shown you.
   Also, you don't escape the values, which may contain characters that are not allowed in XML.
4. `$ch = curl_init($url);`

   `$url` does not exist. The value that you want to use, is in `$post_url`.
5. You are using insecure settings for `cURL`, making your code vulnerable for a MITM attack (SSL server spoofing).
   See [this documentation](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/blob/master/docs/security.md#ssl-server-spoofing) for more information.
6. You don't have any form for error checking.

After fixing the issues, your code looks like this and should now work:

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_73', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2);

function post_to_third_party($entry)
{
    $url      = 'http://mywebsite.co.uk/customers?clientid=1599999&secret=123';
    $encoding = 'WINDOWS-1252';
    $brand    = htmlspecialchars($entry['20'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $product  = htmlspecialchars($entry['22'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $form_id  = htmlspecialchars($entry['21'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $title    = htmlspecialchars($entry['24'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $fname    = htmlspecialchars($entry['23'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $lname    = htmlspecialchars($entry['17'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $postcode = htmlspecialchars($entry['14'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $address1 = htmlspecialchars($entry['2.1'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $address2 = htmlspecialchars($entry['2.2'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $town     = htmlspecialchars($entry['2.3'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);
    $county   = htmlspecialchars($entry['2.4'], ENT_XML1, $encoding);

    $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"$encoding\"?>
    <webform>
        <brand>$brand</brand>
        <product>$product</product>
        <form_id>$form_id</form_id>
        <title>$title</title>
        <fname>$fname</fname>
        <lname>$lname</lname>
        <postcode>$postcode</postcode>
        <address1>$address1</address1>
        <address2>$address2</address2>
        <town>$town</town>
        <county>$county</county>
    </webform>";

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if ($ch === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to initialise a session");
    }

    $result = curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type: text/xml'],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xml,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
    ]);

    if ($result === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to set session options");
    }

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($output === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Request failed: " . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
}
```